# не правильно выводит плитки

Tags: c++, linux, c

Я что-то понаписывал код. Смотрю на него и не могу понять что в нём не так. Я хочу рисовать плитку размером в 64x64, заполнить этой плиткой весь экран, но в на деле выходит так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код, в нём же всё правильно? Я использую одно изображение и рисую им в разных координатах.

```
        for ( int y = 0; y < cf.screen_height; y += 64 ) {
                for ( int x = 0; x < cf.screen_width; x += 64 ) { 
                        tile->transform ( glm::vec3 ( (float) x, (float) y, (float) 0 ) );
                        tile->draw ( );
                }
        }
```

если поменять так код, чтобы выводилось всего по две плитки на строку, то будет такая картина.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
почему то рисуются только последние плитки сверху и справа, но почему?
использую sdl2 + opengl es + glm. 
Сделал видео, видео видно, что сначала не получается отобразить плитки, но в какой то момент плитки рисуются. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_aEBcdprS4&feature=youtu.be
и в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это оказывается проблема в sdl 2.0.10. в этой версии такие проблемы наблюдаются. в версии 2.0.8 таких проблем нет и все плитки нормально отображаются.

Comment: А дело точно не в неопределенном поведении в недрах кода?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat точно. старая версия sdl2 работает как надо и глюков нет.